# Swift store closure with parameter packs

Tags: swift, variadic-functions, parameter-pack, swift5.9

I would like to create a closure type that is always called on the main thread using the new parameter packs introduced in Swift 5.9. E.g.

```swift
protocol Repository {
    func loadData(completion: MainClosure<Result<String, Error>>)
}

class MockRepository: Repository {
    func loadData(completion: MainClosure<Result<String, Error>>) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            // Load some data...

            completion(.success("foo")) // Calls on the main thread
        }
    }
}
```

This is my current implementation, but I get 2 errors.

```swift
public struct MainClosure<each T> {
    private let closure: (repeat each T) -> Void

    public init(_ closure: @escaping (repeat each T) -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure // Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation
    }

    public func callAsFunction(_ parameter: repeat each T) -> Void {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.closure(each parameter) // Error: Cannot pass value pack expansion to non-pack parameter of type 'repeat each T'
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't define the `init` method the compiler manages to do it for me, so there is some way, but I need to define it as `public`.

How can I resolve these issues to a) store the `closure`, b) pass the parameters to it from `callAsFunction`?

Comment: Are you reinventing `@MainActor () -> Void`?

Comment: In general, parameter packs have very limited uses as of right now. They only work in a fixed set of contexts (the parameter list of a closure type is not one of them). If you try using them somewhere else, you'd either get a compiler error or crash the compiler completely.

Comment: Save yourself the headache and just use async await it guarantees that the return will happen in the parent's actor and if you are dealing with UI it will always return on the `MainActor`.

Comment: @Sweeper I can't believe it was that simple. I really need to start implementing async-await, I've just been too lazy on that. Thank you!